# Что не так с медиазапросами

Tags: css

Всем привет! Вот код с медиазапросами

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    body {
        bbackground-color: red;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    body {
        bbackground-color: orange;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
    body {
        bbackground-color: yellow;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    body {
        bbackground-color: green;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Поскажите почему они не работают?

Comment: Нет такого свойства bbackground-color :) Советую использовать какой-то редактор или IDE с подсветкой синтаксиса чтобы не допускать таких ошибок.

Comment: Поддерживаю Igor Tkachuk! Но для редактирования HTML/CSS советую Sublime вместо громоздких IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в синтаксисе, а именно в свойстве `bbackground-color`, нужно исправить на `background-color`.

Comment: Всем спасибо ребята!

Comment: @Евгений Спасибо репутации не добавит. Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как полезный (чекбокс слева от текста ответа)